# Python: Creating a new list from an old list in a new sequence with two-parts

Tags: python

I have a very long list of data that is organized by a date system, which I would like to reorganize and create a new list - so that the data is more intuitive. More below:

The data is organized like:

```
A1, B1, C1 ... L1, A2, B2, ...
```

In essence, each letter stands for a specific month - say october - and the corresponding number the day. There are twelve months, so this pattern repeats itself after every 12th entry.

Furthermore, the data set is setup in this fashion for 20 years straight. So, to go from:

```
A1(1970) to A1(1971)
```

would repeat every 992th entry. Each month has 31 days, invalid values correspond to invalid dates are present as"---". I can delete these later.

My goal is to organize the data calendar style (Oct. 1st, 2nd ... 31st, Nov 1st.. etc) with the correct years.

So far, I can retrieve a list of values organized by month, but not by year. So, I'll have all the values for October for all years, then november for all years, etc.

```
import itertools
discharge = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([dischargeraw[::12] ... 
dischargeraw[11::12]))
```

My problem is that I need to capture the first month (by appending values every 12th) until the 31st value is appended. Then I need it to skip forward 992 values, do the same thing capturing every 12th value 31 times, then skip forward 992. Additionally, this whole process would have to repeat itself twelve times to capture each month in a year, then start up again at the end of the very first cycle - which would be index[31].

In reality, it might have to skip forward 962 (992-31), but these kinds of things I can modify.

Sorry I am pretty new to coding and this is a complicated problem.

Answer (score 0):

Each year takes 372 (31 * 12) consecutive entries to represent. Within a year, each day is at index (day * 12) + month, e.g. March 4th is at 2 * 12 + 4 = 28.

This means that to fetch the entry for a given date, you can do:

```
def get_entry(entries, year, month, day):
  return entries[year * 372 + day * 12 + month]
```

where month and day are zero-indexed, and year is an offset from the first year in the dataset.

To sort the entire dataset, you could do:

```
def get_sorted_entries(entries, num_years):
  sorted_entries = []
  for year in range(num_years):
    for month in range(12):
      for day in range(31):
        sorted_entries.append(get_entry(entries, year, month, day))
  return sorted_entries
```

Comment: If I apply these functions, I receive a list index out of range error for the second line of your first function. If I tweak the amount you multiply either year or month by, I can successfully run the functions, but obviously, the values do not come out correctly. Changing the number of years does the same thing, too. I have 11904 values, which should be 32 years (32*372)

Comment: the day multiplier should be 12, not 31. fixed. this should work correctly, the last day will be year 31, day 30, month 11, ie 31*372 + 30*12 + 11 = 11903, your last valid index.

Comment: I see - it works perfectly for what I need now, and it's pretty easy to understand. Thanks!